# Failing to add items to SugarORM database from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sugarorm

So the problem is that I can't add items into Sugar orm database on a click but I manage to add them to the list. And the strange thing is that it shows me 5 null objects existing in database already. What should I do?

```
 public class FragmentOne extends ListFragment {
private TextView iaDdebt;
private Button btnAdd;
private EditText etAmount;
private List<Debt> values;
String debtTemp;
String temp;


private ArrayAdapter<Debt> adapter;
Debt debt;
List<Debt> loadList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View rootView = lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    iaDdebt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.iaDebt);
    btnAdd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    etAmount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etAmount);
    loadList = Debt.listAll(Debt.class);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.my_list_item, R.id.iaDebt, loadList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            temp = etAmount.getText().toString();
            debt = new Debt(temp);

            loadList.add(debt);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an object, but not actually saving the new record to the DB. Add the save:

```
debt = new Debt(temp);
debt.save();
```